# within() method in HibernateSpatial API is checking one way of Geometry, How to make it for two way?

Tags: hibernate-spatial

I am using Hibernate Spatial API to check a point Inside \ Outside a Polygon.But it is not helping my Usecase.

As per my usecase, I am having a Polygon shape in my db. ***Need to check a Point is inside
/ outside a stored polygon or not ***

- Point(Geometry) is my Input.
- Polygon(Geometry) is stored in my database.
- Everytime I have to check the Input with my Stored Polygon.

  By the within() method (HibernateSpatial API - **NOT MySQL method**), I could able to pass the Point(Geometry). But the method is checking against my usecase.

---

> within method is checking the point containing a polygon or not. So I
>   am getting wrong result in my usecase. See their documentation for reference.

```
   * An implication of the definition is that
   * "The boundary of a Geometry is not within the Geometry".
   * In other words, if a geometry A is a subset of
   * the points in the boundary of a geomtry B, <code>A.within(B) = false</code>
   *
   *@param  g  the <code>Geometry</code> with which to compare this <code>Geometry</code>
   *@return        <code>true</code> if this <code>Geometry</code> is within
   *      <code>other</code>
   *
   * @see Geometry#contains
   */

  public boolean within(Geometry g) {

        return g.contains(this);

  }
```

---

**How to check the polygon inside or outside with Point in HibernateSpatial API. Any help is much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve to check other way. Need to implement another method.The method is following

```
contains(Geometry G)
```

[Documentation clearly says this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-within).